# How to request (GET/POST) routes in RSpec that have a wildcard

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec-rails

I have this (admittedly hideous) route in Rails:

```
scope '/software' do
  post '/:software_id/:attachment_id/event/*event' => 'software#post_event', as: 'post_event'
end
```

(I would change it but for a legacy API)

And I am writing an RSpec test for it.

`rake routes` gives me:

```
post_event POST   /software/:software_id/:attachment_id/event/*event(.:format)     api/version1301/software#post_event
```

My test looks like this:

```
  describe "post_event" do

    it "should respond with 204" do
      params = {
        attachment_id: @attachment.uid,
        software_id: @license.id
      }

      post :post_event, params

      response.code.should eq "204"
    end
  end
```

But I get the following routing error:

```
Failure/Error: post :post_event, params
ActionController::RoutingError:
No route matches {:format=>"json", :name_path=>:api, :attachment=>"7b40ab6a-d522-4a86-b0de-dfb8081e4465", :software_id=>"0000001", :attachment_id=>"7b40ab6a-d522-4a86-b0de-dfb8081e4465", :controller=>"api/version1301/software", :action=>"post_event"}
     # ./spec/controllers/api/version1301/software_controller_spec.rb:62:in `block (4 levels) in '
```

How do you handle the route with the wildcard (event)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

(Answering my own question)

This turned out to be a bit of a 'rookie' mistake.

The wildcard (event) part of the route still requires a parameter. I wasn't passing the 'event' parameter, therefore the route was incomplete.

The following code works:

```
describe "post_event" do

  it "should respond with 204" do
    params = {
      attachment_id: @attachment.uid,
      software_id: @license.id,
      event: 'some/event'
    }

    post :post_event, params

    response.code.should eq "204"
  end
end
```

`/*event(.:format)` means it's expecting a parameter.

Special note to self and others:

**If you ever have routing errors in Rails, verify that you're passing all the parameters.**

Comment: Had a similar problem with an engine mounted inside a scope: scope "*lang" { mount XX::Engine, at: '/' }.  I had to pass in 'lang: "en"' to the `get` in the test to make it work.... that took me 2 days to find.....

Comment: Lately I've been writing [routing specs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/routing-specs) for all non-RESTful routes I encounter. Has saved some headache.